# how to get the first and last value of an array in c?

Tags: c

i got the following code inside a function:

```
    bcc_balancing_status_t balancingStatus;
    uint32_t highestCellvoltage;
    uint32_t lowestCellvoltage;

    uint32_t highestCell;
    uint32_t lowestCell;


    extern uint32_t cell1VoltageUV;
    extern uint32_t cell2VoltageUV;
    extern uint32_t cell3VoltageUV;
    extern uint32_t cell4VoltageUV;
    extern uint32_t cell11VoltageUV;
    extern uint32_t cell12VoltageUV;
    extern uint32_t cell13VoltageUV;
    extern uint32_t cell14VoltageUV;


    int arr[] = {cell1VoltageUV, cell2VoltageUV, cell3VoltageUV, cell4VoltageUV, cell11VoltageUV, cell12VoltageUV, cell13VoltageUV, cell14VoltageUV};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    bubbleSort(arr, n);
    printf("Sorted array: \n");
    printArray(arr, n);


    highestCellvoltage = //should be the actual value of the cellxVoltageUV ex. 3345688  //
    lowestCellvoltage = //should be the actual value of the cellxVoltageUV ex. 3345688  //

    highestCell = // should be 0 for cell 1, 1 for cell 2 etc.  //
    lowesCell = // should be 0 for cell 1, 1 for cell 2 etc.  //

    printf("voltage of highest cell = %lu \n" highestCellvoltage);
    printf("voltage of lowest cell = %lu \n" lowestCellvoltage);

    if((highestCellvoltage-LowestCellvoltage) > 500){

        BCC_CB_Enable(drvConfig, BCC_CID_DEV1, false);
        balancingStatus = BCC_CB_SetIndividual(drvConfig, BCC_CID_DEV1, highestCell, true, 2);

        printf("currently balancing cell %lu", (highestCell+1));

        return BCC_BALANCING_ON;
        }
        else
        {
            return BCC_BALANCING_OFF;
        }
```

the array gets sorted by function bubblesort and after that i want it to find the first and last value of the array so i can determine the difference between these two.
the result of the printarray is:

```
Sorted array: 
3342941 3343399 3343552 3344620 3345688 3345993 3346451 3349960
```

how can i find the first and last values of this array(see notes in code above)? (SOLVED)

not solved yet:
so for example if cell 2 (cell2VoltageUV) has the highest value, i want `highestCell` to be set to 1(because the actual cell count starts from 0 and BCC_CB_Enable needs a value from 0 to 13).

Comment: `first = arr[0]; last=arr[n-1];` ?

Comment: thanks, that solves the first part of my question. do you also happen to know how to solve the last part of the question?

Comment: You can't solve the second part **after** the array has been sorted but it's easy to find the values before the array is sorted - see the posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't find the original index of an element **after** the array has been sorted. It's impossible.

But **before** you sort the array simply do:

```
highestCell = 0;
highestCellvoltage = arr[0];

lowestCell = 0;
lowestCellvoltage = arr[0];

for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
{
    if (arr[i] > highestCellvoltage)
    {
        highestCell = i;
        highestCellvoltage = arr[i];
    }
    else if (arr[i] < lowestCellvoltage)
    {
        lowestCell = i;
        lowestCellvoltage = arr[i];
    }
}

// Add bubbleSort(arr, n); here - if needed
```

After that you can sort the array (if it's still needed).